# How would I assess goodness-of-fit considering single participants?

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, psychology

I am designing a psychology experiment which is designed to look at the proportion of different types of errors people make.

There will be four response categories: correct; incorrect [type 1; type 2; type 3].

Ignoring the correct category, one could then compare expected versus observed error proportions (or counts) for each response category using some goodness-of-fit test, like a chi-square test. However, I don't believe it would be statistically valid can create mean proportions (or counts) across participants and assess GoF using this data, as you might do in an ANOVA.

Normally, each participant provides their own single datapoint for a cell. But in my proposed design, I would be conducting one chi-square test on the expected versus observed proportions (or counts) for each subject.

Is there a more elegant way of conducting such an analysis? A single model goodness-of-fit test that accounts for the data for individual participants? How would this be implemented in, say, R?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you clarify what you want to know? Or what your null hypothesis is?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks. My alternative hypothesis is that there will be larger counts of one particular error type than the other two error types. I think this data might be described using a poisson distribution, actually (e.g. type 1 errors n = 33, type 2 errors n = 15, type 3 errors n = 6). The null would be that the error counts are equally distributed across types (e.g. all error n's = 18). The precise distribution shape isn't a hypothesis I'm making, it was just an example.

Comment: And will this be a different error type for each person? Or the same?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply! This would be the same error types for each person.

so all participants will be capable of producing type 1, type 2 and type 3 errors due to the experiment design.